# jquery and .attri doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
function init(){
    $.get(URL, function(data) {
     DATA = data;
     var srcWithHead = URL + "/" + $(DATA).find("img").attr("src");
     $(DATA).find("img").attr("src", srcWithHead);
     console.log("src = " + $(DATA).find("img").attr("src"));
    });
}
```

And I would like to have a picture showing. But the URL image src is a relative path. So, I need to have a header of each image. But it seems that 
`$(DATA).find("img").attr("src", srcWithHead);`
doesn't work.

What can I do? and any other method?
Thanks

Comment: what does `console.log("src = " + $(DATA).find("img").attr("src"));` gives you??

Comment: is your data return from the ajax a string type?

Comment: I want to see if the src changed or not

It should be string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have multiple IMG tags. Use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to access each one.

```
function init(){
    $.get(URL, function(data) {
    DATA = data;
    $(DATA).find("img").each(function() {
        var srcWithHead = URL + "/" + $(this).attr("src");
        $(DATA).find("img").attr("src", srcWithHead);
    });
}
```

Comment: THX
It seems work. But only for the console. It cannot show too. At least the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with attr today and the following works for me.

```
 $('#ctl00_Content_imgbtnDiscardQuote')
    .attr('src','').attr('value','Cancel').attr('type','submit');
```

Try running `$(DATA);` in firebug or chrome console, it may not be returning what you think.

**Edit** try .each()

```
$(DATA).find('img').each(function(index){ 
    $(this).attr('src','/myimg.jpg'); 
});
```

Welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: because in my $(DATA), I have more than img item. So, I need to find it first.
I am not sure what you are talking. Could you explain more? And you can solve it, right?

Thx, I am a new one.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work with multiple items. However you can try using $(DATA).each();

See the edit above.

Comment: I looked up the documentation. Seems you were correct, it only works on one element.

".attr() ... Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: Thanks, i am trying each()
but it seems that there is some error

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're not finding any elements?

Try

```
alert($(DATA));
alert($(DATA).length);
alert($(DATA).find('img').length);
```

Comment: No, I find it and it can show the pages. But the src doesn't change. It remains the same.

Comment: @Ian: what do you mean by *show the pages*? what pages? what i'm saying is that if either `$(DATA)` or `.find('img')` returns an empty object, then your code will work, but no images will be changed. please note that if you're trying to change more than one image, you're changing them all to *same* src with this code, as the  `srcWithHead` variable will only hold one src. if you want to make a change relative to each picture, and you're on jquery1.4, you can do `$(DATA).find('img').attr('src', function() { return URL + '/' + $(this).attr('src'); });`.

Comment: also note (altho this is probably not the cause of your problems) that you're greating a *global* variable `DATA` here, since you're introducing it without the `var` keyword. why not use the `data` variable you've already got, instead?

Answer (score 0):

try to eval your `data`, i'm not sure here since I don't know what would be the data be, but give this a try.

```
function init(){
    $.get(URL, function(data) {
       DATA = eval("("+data+")"); // treat the data as json object
       var srcWithHead = URL + "/" + $(DATA).find("img").attr("src");
       $(DATA).find("img").attr("src", srcWithHead);
       console.log("src = " + $(DATA).find("img").attr("src"));
    });
}
```